# I have a question about implementing the camera shooting and editing functions

Tags: android, ios, video, camera, record

I am trying to create a video platform app that includes camera shooting and editing functions. I have a question about implementing the camera shooting and editing functions.
hello.

We are in the process of developing a video platform app that includes camera shooting and editing functions through an external developer.
The first communication was to minimize camera shooting and editing functions, and these functions included:

- Camera function running inside the app
- Playing background music during video recording and filming
- After shooting, there is no need for editing to add effects such as filters.
- After filming, it can be cut to a specific length.
- After filming, adjust the volume between the sound recorded during filming and separate background music.

This is how we communicated,

After searching, the developer found that there was no open source that implemented the function, and their position was that it would not fit the budget to implement the function by modifying the existing open source.

I'm asking a question because I don't have enough knowledge about app development, and I couldn't understand it clearly even after searching separately.

What I'm curious about is whether there is actually no open source that can implement the functionality described above, or if it is possible to modify the open source to some extent, I would like to know how difficult it would be. (They say they use React Native and Spring Boot.)

We plan to conduct further research based on your response and then communicate objectively.

I looked for information related to my question.
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera
https://github.com/anday2000/ReactNative-VideoEditor

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.